# How to prevent Duplicate records from my table Insert ignore does not work here

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

```
mysql> select * from emp;

    +-----+---------+------+------+------+
    | eno | ename   | dno  | mgr  | sal  |
    +-----+---------+------+------+------+
    |   1 | rama    |    1 | NULL | 2000 |
    |   2 | kri     |    1 |    1 | 3000 |
    |   4 | kri     |    1 |    2 | 3000 |
    |   5 | bu      |    1 |    2 | 2000 |
    |   6 | bu      |    1 |    1 | 2500 |
    |   7 | raa     |    2 | NULL | 2500 |
    |   8 | rrr     |    2 |    7 | 2500 |
    |   9 | sita    |    2 |    7 | 1500 |
    |  10 | dlksdgj |    2 |    2 | 2000 |
    |  11 | dlksdgj |    2 |    2 | 2000 |
    |  12 | dlksdgj |    2 |    2 | 2000 |
    |  13 | dlksdgj |    2 |    2 | 2000 |
    |  14 | dlksdgj |    2 |    2 | 2000 |
    +-----+---------+------+------+------+
```

Here is my table. I want to *eliminate* or *prevent* insertion of the duplicate records, as the `eno` field is `auto increment` total row never be duplicate, but the records are duplicates. How can I prevent inserting those duplicate records?

I tried using `INSERT IGNORE AND ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (*I think I have not used them properly*).

The way I used them is,

```
mysql> insert into emp(ename,dno,mgr,sal) values('dlksdgj',2,2,2000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into emp(ename,dno,mgr,sal) values('dlksdgj',2,2,2000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into emp(ename,dno,mgr,sal) values('dlksdgj',2,2,2000) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE eno=eno;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
mysql> insert into emp(ename,dno,mgr,sal) values('dlksdgj',2,2,2000) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE eno=eno;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec

mysql> desc emp;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| eno   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ename | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dno   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mgr   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sal   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: can you post the result of this query `DESC Employee`?

Comment: what is the column(s) you want values to be unique?

Comment: can anybody give me any other more optimized query for this..??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

alter the table by adding `UNIQUE` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT emp_unique UNIQUE (ename,dno,mgr,sal)
```

but you can do this if the table `employee` is empty.

or if records existed, try adding `IGNORE`

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT emp_unique UNIQUE (ename,dno,mgr,sal)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Something went wrong, I guess. You only need to add unique constraint on column `ename` since `eno` will always be unique due to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

In order to add unique constraint, you need to do some cleanups on your table.

The queries below delete some duplicate records, and alters table by adding unique constraint on column `ename`.

```
DELETE a
FROM Employee a
     LEFT JOIN
     (
        SELECT ename, MIN(eno) minEno
        FROM Employee
        GROUP BY ename
     ) b ON a.eno = b.minEno
WHERE b.minEno IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT emp_unique UNIQUE (ename);
```

Here's a full demonstration

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29964/1)

Comment: is there any other way ...than using this unique key constraint as I dont have permission to change the table structure...can't I eliminate it before inserting itself without using unique

Comment: uhmm, *I think*, **none** since you have no privilege on altering the table. the only way to do that is to check it against the table for record existence.

Comment: you can check the record by executing this query first `SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount FROM emp WHERE ename = 'nameHere'"`, if the result is greater than or equal to 1, then the value existed.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on which you think the duplicacy exist .

like

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT constraint1 UNIQUE(column1, column2, column3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work regardless of whether you clean up your table first (i.e. you can stop inserting duplicates immediately and clean up on separate schedule) and without having to add any unique constraints or altering table in any other way:

```
INSERT INTO
    emp (ename, dno, mgr, sal)
SELECT
    e.ename, 2, 2, 2000
FROM
    (SELECT 'dlksdgj' AS ename) e
    LEFT JOIN emp ON e.ename = emp.ename
WHERE
    emp.ename IS NULL
```

The above query assumes you want to use `ename` as a "unique" field, but in the same way you could define any other fields or their combinations as unique for the purposes of this `INSERT`.

It works because it's an `INSERT ... SELECT` format where the `SELECT` part only produces a row (i.e. something to insert) if its left joined `emp` does not already have that value. Naturally, if you wanted to change which field(s) defined this "uniqueness" you would modify the `SELECT` and the `LEFT JOIN` accordingly.