# How to prevent duplicate insert from csv to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How to prevent insert if email exist

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['btn_import']))
{
    $filename = 'Database.csv';
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, "40", ",")) != FALSE)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO excel (name,email,phone_no) VALUES('" . implode("','", $row) . "')";
        if (!$conn->query($sql))
        {
            echo '<br>Data No Insert<br>';
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

ps. this code its from stackoverflow

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028093/how-to-prevent-duplicate-records-from-my-table-insert-ignore-does-not-work-here

Comment: Well first you check the database to see if email exists, then you dont run the INSERT if it does. **Simples**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to do this.

1. Clean your csv before trying to insert : `$csv[$row[$emailColId]] = $row` for example
2. Before every insert, use `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE email = $email`
3. In your table definition, add an Index on email, set it to UNIQUE and deal with query() returning true / false or exceptions thrown

To me, the best choice would be the 3rd point.

Comment: Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE `excel` ADD UNIQUE(`email`);
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'email' for key 'email'

Comment: This clearly tells you already have duplicated email in your table. `SELECT email, COUNT(email) FROM excel GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1` will show you duplicated data.